# object changing position when scaled

Tags: opengl, glsl

These are my matrices.
when i move the pivot point to one unit in x and if the scaling is set to 1 than everthing works fine.

[image]

the pivot point has moved to one unit and the cube has stayed in its position.

But when i first scale the object to 0.5 and than move the pivot point than the cube follows the pivot point , which should not be he case as i am only moving pivot point.

Please help me with this , how can i keep the cube in position.

[image]

```
 glm::mat4x4 Container::GetPositionMatrix()
  {
     // posx  is the x position of the object.
     // posy  is the y position of the object.
    // posz  is the y position of the object.     
       glm::mat4 TransformationPosition = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0), 
       glm::vec3(posx , posy   , posz ));
      return TransformationPosition;
   }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 glm::mat4x4 Container::GetRotationMatrix()
 {
      //  posx  is the x positon of the object
      // pivotx is the x position on the pivot point
      // rotx is the x rotation of the object
      glm::vec3 pivotVector(posx - pivotx, posy - pivoty, posz - pivotz);
      glm::mat4 TransPivot = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), pivotVector);
      glm::mat4 TransPivotInverse = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), 
      glm::vec3( -pivotVector.x , -pivotVector.y , -pivotVector.z));
      glm::mat4 TransformationRotation(1.0);
      TransformationRotation = glm::rotate(TransformationRotation, 
      glm::radians(rotx ), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
      TransformationRotation = glm::rotate(TransformationRotation, 
     glm::radians(roty ), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
     TransformationRotation = glm::rotate(TransformationRotation, 
     glm::radians(rotz  ), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
     return  TransPivotInverse * TransformationRotation * TransPivot;
  }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  glm::mat4x4 Container::GetScalingMatrix()
      {

      //  posx  is the x positon of the object
      // pivotx is the x  position on the pivot point
      // scax is the x scaling of the object
      glm::vec3 pivotVector(posx - pivotx, posy - pivoty, posz - pivotz);
      glm::mat4 TransPivot = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), pivotVector);
      glm::mat4 TransPivotInverse = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), 
      glm::vec3(-pivotVector.x, -pivotVector.y, -pivotVector.z));       
      glm::mat4 TransformationScale = glm::scale(glm::mat4x4(1.0 ) , 
      glm::vec3(scax, scay, scaz));
      return  TransPivotInverse * TransformationScale  * TransPivot;
```

}

```
 final matrix

 TransformationPosition * TransformationRotation  * TransformationScaling
```

Comment: Why do you scale using pivot?

Comment: @Ocelot  in the application a user has the ability to move the pivot and that do scaling and rotation with respect to pivot point location.

Comment: @Ocelot please have a look at the video link.   

Video Link for the issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uS9jTgj6i4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Pivot should move scaled object https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2fnx7wag15
Try to inverse pivot transformation order.

Comment: @Ocelot It is same here desmos.com/calculator/2fnx7wag15 as in my application i can move the pivot freely when the scale is 1 but when i change the scae the points also move along pivot.

Comment: I want the pivot to move freely even if the scale is not 1 , the points should not move along the pivot.

Comment: Then don't use pivot for scaling

Comment: For certain scenarios the user will require to scale with offset pivot.

Comment: Is it possible to add position to cube when i move my pivot so it stays in its position.

Comment: Then add separate pivot for scaling

Comment: @Ocelot this is what i want to attain.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nqG8oBB9IM&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Scale pivoting is certainly supposed to translate your object, as demonstrated [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fvfnoqq1av).

But, in the reference video you linked, did you notice that when you move pivot point, position of the object changes as well? You should do the same thing when you move pivot in your application, by subtracting difference to the object's position in order to compensate.

This is how to find difference:

```
glm::vec3 difference = position - pivot * scale;
```